# Somar ou Mostrar quantidade de itens

Tags: php, mysql

Qual a melhor maneira de somar ou mostrar a quantidade de itens numa tabela mysql utilizando o php.

Pois quando executo esse código aparece o seguinte erro:
 `Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in H:\Web\root\index.php on line 89`

```
$mysql_connection =  mysql_connect($web_host, $web_user, $web_pass);
        $mysql_connection_from_db = mysql_select_db($web_db);

        $command_ = "SELECT COUNT(`usr_id`) FROM `app_users`";      
        $mysql_query = mysql_query($command_);      

        $num = mysql_num_rows($mysql_query);

        if(0 == $num) { $PESSOAS = 0; }
        else{
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($mysql_query)) 
            {
                $PESSOAS = $PESSOAS + 1;
            }
        }
```

Linha 89:

```
$num = mysql_num_rows($mysql_query);
```

OBS: O objetivo é que o usuário clique em participar e ele adicione um nome qualquer mais um id na tabela e quando carregar a página o sistema php mostra quantos itens tem naquela tabela, ou no caso, `$PESSOAS`, que determina o número de participantes.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode pegar o resultado direto com o `mysql_fetch_assoc()` ou `mysql_fetch_array()`.

```
$command_ = "SELECT COUNT(`usr_id`) FROM `app_users`";      
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($command_));
```

O `COUNT()` sempre irá retornar apenas 1 linha, por isso o erro do seu código, você está fazendo um looping.

E uma dica, não utilize o `mysql_connect()` ele esta deprecated, utilize a função `mysqli_connect()`.

Comment: mas o mysqli é o mesmo do mysql? ou uma linguagem sql diferente?

Comment: É o mesmo do mysql (http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysqli-connect.php)

Comment: ok vou tentar! : )

Comment: ops! mantem o mesmo **mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in H:\Web\root\index.php on line 86**

Comment: ja troquei pelo mysqli

Comment: Jeferson Assis eu quero fazer esse sistema igual ao do stackoverflow quando um usuário abre uma pergunta aqui no site, mostra o número de visualizações entendeu? mas quando um usuário se cadastra no site aparece quantos usuários estão cadastrados.

Comment: Entendi, quando você roda essa query direto no banco de dados te retorna algum dado? 
[Neste link](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysqli-connect.php#112689) tem um exemplo de como fazer a consulta, porém na sua não irá precisar do `while()` você pode pegar direto como mostrei na resposta

Comment: Olha quando eu executo no phpmyadmin ele me retorna uma tabela indicando a quantidade. ex:

-------------------<br>
+-- COUNT --+<br>
------------------<br>
1

Comment: Ops, quando eu uso mysqli_query aparece o seguinte: **Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in H:\Web\root\index.php on line 86

Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in H:\Web\root\index.php on line 86**

Comment: apareceu mais um quando eu hospedei os arquivos na nuvem... **Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/a1478344/public_html/warface/index.php on line 86**

Comment: Segue este link para a demonstração : http://brasilr2.net76.net/warface/

Comment: Olha tentei executar isso e aparece apenas o numero 1: **$PESSOAS = mysqli_num_rows( mysqli_query( $mysql_connection ,$command_ ));**

Answer (score 0):

Funcionou deste jeito!

Com base da resposta do Jeferson Assis pude compreender que não é preciso executar

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `participacoes`
```

Mas sim executar:

```
SELECT * FROM `participacoes`
```

E proseguir com o php:

```
$mysql_connection =  mysqli_connect($web_host, $web_user, $web_pass, $web_db);   
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `participacoes`';             
$PESSOAS = mysqli_num_rows( mysqli_query( $mysql_connection , $sql ));
```

Note que eu apenas utilizei apenas para que o sistema conte o número de itens não o total do número de itens:

`$PESSOAS = mysqli_num_rows( mysqli_query( $mysql_connection , $sql ));`

se não acabaria num loop infinito e não seria reposto nenhum dado.